# Need Desired date format in vertica

Tags: vertica

I am facing one simple issues in vertica.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

OutPut:

```
01/18/2021
```

But the requirement is Output should be like below:

OutPut:

```
1/18/2021
```

Can anyone please help me to get like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the leading zero using the [FM Modifier](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TemplatePatternModifiersForDateTimeFormatting.htm):

```
dbadmin=> select to_char(sysdate, 'FMMM/DD/YYYY');
  to_char
-----------
 1/18/2021
(1 row)
```